# JBoss - Configuration for ssl_error_weak_server_ephemeral_dh_key

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, jboss

I tried changing cipher suites listed in [this](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS) URL. But still i get secure connection failed error in mozilla firefox.

What are the supported cipher suites?
Can we change DH Parameter size & RSA key size in JBoss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little google on this subject and i will summarise here.

DH Parameter Size can be set using a System property ( add it as JVM option if you cannot use System.setProperty()). 2048 bit is recommended size and 1024 is minimum size for safety. This parameter can be set by-

```
-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
```

More over, to prevent client initiated renegotiation (secured or non-secured), we can use the following JVM options-

```
jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
```

This will work with any Java EE container that runs on Hotspot VM.

Note: DH key size can be customized only in Java 8. And the value should be only 768, 1024 or 2048 bits only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!!  this worked for me for Jboss 4.2.3 porting liferay 3.6 or 4.0  relating to the Firefox security updates...

I had to upgrade to Java 8 to make these changes
also `server.xml` needed the following line added to the SSL Connector

```
SSLCipherSuite="ALL:!ADH:!SSLv2:!EXPORT40:!EXP:!LOW"
```

ciphers= will not work for older jBoss. This temporary fix will get old code working and secure.  now I'll work on a permanent fix.